Projection of real representations onto the isotypic components
Let $(V, \rho)$ be a representation of a finite group $G$ over field $\mathbb{F}$ and $W_i$ be irreducible representations (irreps) of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}$ with dimension $d_i$ and character $\chi_i$. Suppose $$V \cong \bigoplus_i W_i^{n_i}$$ be the decomposition of $V$ to its isotypic components.
If $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, then $$p_i=\frac{d_i}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\bar{\chi_i}(g)\rho_g$$ is the projection of V onto $W_i^{n_i}$ with respect to the given decomposition.
Now, let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$. Then $p_i$ with the given definition is not projection unless $W_i$ is a real-type irrep. I want to find the projection V onto $W_i^{n_i}$ with respect to the given decomposition when $W_i$ is a complex-type or quaternion-type irrep. I did that as follows:

Assume $W_i$ is a complex-type irrep. There is irrep $W_i^0$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with dimension $d_i^0$ character $\chi_i^0$ such that $W_i \otimes \mathbb{C}=W_i^0 \oplus (W_i^0)^*$, $\chi_i=\chi_i^0+\bar{\chi_i^0}$, and $d_i^0=\frac{d_i}{2}$.
Hence, the projection can be defined as follows:
$$p_i=\frac{d_i^0}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\bar{\chi_i^0}(g)\rho_g + \frac{d_i^0}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_i^0(g)\rho_g=\frac{d_i^0}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}(\bar{\chi_i^0}+\chi_i^0)(g)\rho_g= \frac{d_i}{2|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_i(g)\rho_g $$
Assume $W_i$ is a quaternion-type irrep. There is irrep $W_i^0$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with dimension $d_i^0$ character $\chi_i^0$ such that $W_i \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong W_i^0 \oplus W_i^0$, $\chi_i=2\chi_i^0$, and $d_i^0=\frac{d_i}{2}$.
Hence, the projection can be defined as follows:
$$p_i=\frac{d_i^0}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_i^0(g)\rho_g + \frac{d_i^0}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_i^0(g)\rho_g= \frac{d_i^0}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}2\chi_i^0(g)\rho_g= \frac{d_i}{2|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_i(g)\rho_g$$
So to mix all these, let $\mu=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g} \chi_i(g^2)$ be the Schur indicator of $\chi_i$, then we can define the projection as follows:
$$p_i=\frac{2d_i}{(4-\mu-\mu^2)|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g) \rho_g$$

Is this correct? How can I make it more rigorous? I feel it is not rigorous since the relation between $W_i$ and $W_i^0$ comes from the complexification of $W_i$ while I am not mentioning the complexification in the projection.
Added
Based on the comments the projections seems to be $$p_i=\frac{d_i}{\dim\Big(\text{End}_G(W_i)\Big))|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \chi_i(g) \rho_g$$
Why did I go wrong in the quaternion-type irreps?

I agree with the first part, not the second. If $W_i$ is of quaternion type, the projection on $W_i \otimes \mathbb{C} = (W_i^0)^2$ is simply the projection on $W_i^0$. So at the end you get $\frac{d_i}{4|G|}$. I don't really understand why this does not seem rigorous to you, you could maybe add some details to your interrogation.

I find what you found pretty interesting. You may know that the reason why real representations are called of real, complex and quaternion-type is because their endomorphism ring are respectively isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ which are respectively of dimension 1, 2 and 4 over $\mathbb{R}$. So it seems like the general formula for the projection is just the usual divided by the dimension of the endomorphism ring.

If you are familiar with the notion of Schur index $($which is different from the Schur indicator$)$, I think that you could easily extend this result for representation on representation over any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

Thx for the explanation, I do not see it is rigorous because If $W_i = W_i^0 \oplus \bar{W_i}^0$, then I would have said "$p_i$ is the summation of projections onto $W_i^0$ and $\bar{W_i}^0$ ". However, $W_i \otimes \mathbb{C}= W_i^0 \oplus \bar{W_i}^0$, and I do not know how to consider the fact that $W_i$ requires complexification.

Do you mean that you want of formal proof that the projection formula for $W_i \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is the same as the projection formula for $W_i$ ?

Oh, is that so? yes, it would be helpful to see that. Would you also say why in the quaternion-type projection for the $W_i$ and $W_i^0$ are essentially the same? If I consider projections as operators, it kind of makes sense. However, seeing them as matrices makes me confuse when the dimension of $W_i$ is twice that of $W_i^0$

Just by seeing $W_i \otimes \mathbb{C} = W_i \oplus iW_i$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, You have a natural embedding of $W_i$ into its complexification by associating any vector $v$ in $W_i$ to $v \otimes 1$. And because your projection is the identity on the whole space, it is also on $W_i$ as a subspace of $W_i \otimes \mathbb{C}$.

The projection formula in the complex case is not for one subrepresentation isomorphic to $W_i^0$, it is the projection on the sum of all the subrepresentations isomorphic to $W_i^0$. So the formula is the same for $W_i^0$, $W_i^0 \oplus W_i^0$ or $(W_i^0)^{n_i}$ for any integer $n_i$. The reason why this does not contradict the argument on the dimension that you made is that because this is a direct sum of representation, the matrices of your representation are just formed of $n_i$ diagonal blocks, each of them being the matrix representation of $W_i^0$.

It is the same for the projection. The projection matrix of the projection on $W_i^0$ appears $n_i$ times on the diagonal of the matrix of the projection on the whole $(W_i^0)^{n_i}$.
